# mongodb low cpu utilization

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pymongo

I have two instances running on AWS (EC2). One instance is running only mongodb server while the other one is running a multi process python program that acquires info from the remote mongo server.
On the python instance I am using pymongo, and each process establishes connection (MongoClient) independently.

While monitoring the CPU utilization of the mongo's instance, I get very low CPU usage (about 2%).

In the free monitoring tool (https://cloud.mongodb.com/freemonitoring/cluster), I get about 40% CPU utilization.

- Why there is such a big difference between the two values?
- Does the mongodb needs to be special configured in order to utilize multiple CPU's cores?

Comment: What does `top` say for CPU usage?

Comment: same as the free monitoring, about 40%.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the mongodb needs to be special configured in order to utilize multiple CPU's cores?

No.

> Why there is such a big difference between the two values?

You have not described where the 2% value came from or what it is measuring, hence this question is impossible to answer.